# Are all of the following statements equivalent? (vectors and matrices)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors

I know there's a theorem in linear algebra that has a list of statements that are equivalent, as follows:

1. $\det(A) \ne 0$
2. $Ax = 0$ has only the trivial solution
3. $Ax = b$ is consistent for every matrix $b$
4. $Ax = b$ has exactly one solution for every $n \times 1$ matrix $b$

(and several other which I do not need for the question that I'd like to ask).

So we've been learning about linear independence, span and bases, and I was wondering the following:

Is statement 2 the same as saying a set of vectors are linearly independent?

Is statement 3 the same as saying the set of vectors span a vector space? (Meaning that every single vector $b$ in the vector space can be made from some combination of $Ax$, where $A$ would represent that vectors and $x$ would be all of the scalar multiples of the vectors?

Is statement 4 the same as saying the set of vectors is a basis? (since that one solution must be the trivial solution, it must be linearly independent, and since it is consistent for every $b$, it spans the vector space?)

It seems pretty obvious that it's all related to each other, but I'm just wondering if they're all exactly the same.

Comment: You write about "a set of vectors" and "the set of vectors", but you never tell us which set of vectors you mean. $Ax=0$ and $Ax=b$ are equations, they aren't sets of vectors. If you're going to get anywhere in Linear Algebra, you have to be a lot more precise in your use of the language.

Comment: To be honest, while writing this, I thought I WASN'T being that precise, but I just didn't know how to be precise. Usually in the problems I'm given a set of vectors...which I write them as a system of linear equations. The coefficient matrix A seems to represent the vectors in the given set, and the column vector x represents the scalars used to create a linear combination...so would this be more precise:

statement 2 is equal to saying that the set of vectors represented by the coefficient matrix A in the equation Ax = b is linearly independent because the solution matrix x is 0 ?

Comment: It's not more precise, until you explain what you mean by a matrix representing a set of vectors.

Comment: Are you still here?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP has abandoned it.

Comment: Every example I've seen about linear independence or dependence goes like this: 1. a set of vectors is given to me 2. i am asked to determine linear dependence 3. rewrite set of vectors in component form. 4. Equate corresponding components on the two sides, which yields a homogenous linear system of equations. If it is a square matrix, solve the system of compute the coefficient determinent.

Comment: The example I'm looking at in the book is to determine whether the vectors v1 = (1, -2, 3), v2 = (5, 6, -1) v3 = (3,2,1) are linearly dependent. After writing it in component form and equating corresponding components, the coefficient matrix to solve looks as follows: A = [1 5 3; -2 6 2; 3 -1 1]

Comment: The coefficient matrix LITERALLY has the same values as the vectors originally given, so that is why I said it "represents the set of vectors." I don't know how else that would be worded to make it more precise.

Comment: OK, so, the vectors you are talking about are the columns of the matrix you are talking about. That's easy to say, and quite precise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(2) is the same as saying the columns of $A$ are linearly independent.

(3) is the same as saying the columns of $A$ span ${\bf R}^n$, where $n$ is the number of rows of $A$.

(4) is the same thing as saying the columns of $A$ are a basis for ${\bf R}^n$. [I assume $Ax-b$ is a typo for $Ax=b$.]

Answer (score 1):

Your descriptions for (2) and (3) sound good.  I wouldn't say (4) is quite a direct translation of the statement that the columns of $A$ form a basis, although it's of course equivalent and it's easy to see that (4) implies (2) and (3).